# Unsubscribe v/s Unique Unsubscribe

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, custom-reports, unsubscribe, allrows

Anybody knows what's the difference in Discover Report about Unsubscribe v/s Unique Unsubscribe.

I created a report by month and the numbers between the two measurements is so different. I attached the image. It's like the Unique Unsubscribe is half.

In the image each row is a Business Unit.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Has to do with clicks.

Unique is a counter that will only count the first time that the link is clicked. Unsubscribes counts how many times the link was clicked in total. You might double click that link for example and the unsubscribes column would count it as two clicks.

Comment: I understand, Cameron. But if the the link is clicked not necessarily the subscribed will unsubscribed, correct?

Comment: If they click unsubscribe from a MC footer unsubscribe they will in one click, I tested it on my org and confirmed that. They get a choice in what they unsubscribe to via publication lists which would be the "Manage Subscriptions" button in the MC footer.

Comment: Thanks, @Cameron :)

Comment: Sure thing! Cheers @Joano!